# adding elements using an array via appendChild

Tags: javascript

```js
var text = [];

function create() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    text[i] = document.createElement("div");
    text[i].className = "di";
    text[i].innerHTML = "hello world";
    console.log(text[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(text[i]);
  }
}
create();
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
}
```

I am getting a console error during rendering in Microsoft Edge Version 112.0.1722.34 (Official build) (64-bit) with the error: **caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')**, please explain.

Note: observe it runs without errors in the SO snippet.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that can be run to directly see the error, preferably by updating the snippet in your question.

Comment: Please check and run snippet

Comment: to see the error run in edge browser and observe console,

Comment: There is no error in Edge for me.

Comment: i ran in Microsoft Edge Version 112.0.1722.34 (Official build) (64-bit) so then maybe some useragent setting issue or something else ? .by the way @mamun answer worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')"

occurs because the code is trying to append an element to a non-existent element or a *null* element.

In this case, it is possible that the JavaScript code is being executed before the DOM (Document Object Model) has finished loading, and the *document.body* element is not yet available. As a result, the document.body returns null, and the `appendChild()` method cannot be called on it.

To fix this error, you can either move the script tag to the end of the HTML file, just before the closing  tag, or wrap the entire JavaScript code in a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event listener, which will ensure that the code is executed only after the DOM has finished loading.

Try:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 var text = [];

 function create() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
     text[i] = document.createElement("div");
     text[i].className = "di";
     text[i].innerHTML = "hello world";
     console.log(text[i]);
     document.body.appendChild(text[i]);
   }
 }
 create();
});
```